# Font loading in Safari but not Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I am attempting to use the following webfont kit from Font Squirrel on a webpage - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/DJ-Gross

On the 'Webfont kit' tab on the above page, I selected 'No subsetting' form the dropdown and then clicked 'DOWNLOAD @FONT_FACE KIT'

I think font squirrel does a great job of setting out the @font-face declaration for you so I have just used this in my css and moved the font files (.eot, .svg, .ttf, and .woff) to an appropriate directory to use on my site where fairly sure filepaths are referenced correctly.

This font is rendering in Safari but not Chrome

Disregarding my webpage, this can be reproduced by opening the DJGROSS.html file that comes with the Font Squirrel download. Again, this demo works in Safari but not Chrome and I have not touched *this* code at all :)

**EDIT:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'dj_grossnormal';
  src: url('DJGROSS-webfont.eot');
  src: url('DJGROSS-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('DJGROSS-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('DJGROSS-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('DJGROSS-webfont.svg#dj_grossnormal') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}
```

All the font files are in the same directory as my style.css file where this @font-face declaration is

Comment: Can't really help with no code, jsFiddle or anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is working... look this [image](http://prntscr.com/57z01v) try to clean you Google Chrome!

Comment: ahhh, thanks so much for this :)
Guess I will take a look at what could be messing with this in my instance of Chrome :-/

Comment: Thanks again. fwiw, looks like the problem is isolated to Chrome on Mac, working fine when I just tested on Win7 machine. On the Mac, I have also cleared browsing history and tried running Chrome with --disable-extensions but still does not render :(

Comment: For the record, I download the DJGROSS webfontkit on a Windows 8 machine and it's not rendering for me, either. I'm still unsure why, but the only thing that comes to my mind is the package might contain a bad woff file.

Comment: Diego - fontsquirrel uses images on it's websites to demo it's fonts. Just because you see it in your browser on fontsquirrel's site, doesn't mean it's working.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the dev console and see what files the browser is pulling from your site, you'll be able to see if it's downloading the font file in safari.  Some more information like this will help us to answer your question.

Comment: So, still using the font-squirrel demo as an example to test; all these files are local on my machine.

Safari looks like it is loading the .woff file.
Looking in Chrome devtools under 'Sources' I cannot see it loading any font files. However, looking under 'Network' tab it loads the .woff and the .ttf files

Comment: Chrome actually loads both the `woff` and the `ttf` (presumably because it found that the `woff` was corrupted or something). Anyway, I see the same problem on my Windows 8 machine - my guess the font files in the package are bad.